# 2 valued function defined on a connected set must be a constant function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

How to prove by definition that 2 valued function defined on a connected set must be a constant function. I know how to prove the statement but i wanna know how to apply the $\epsilon- \delta$ definition of continuous functions to prove it. I guess may be using the contra positive or contradiction would allow to apply but not sure how to do it.

Comment: I think that you want to show that if X is connected then any continuous function from X to {0,1} must be constant

Comment: @Amr yup, but i wanna apple the definition as well in the proof.

Comment: Do you know the fact that if f is continous and U is open then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open

Comment: @Amr of course, i know that theorem.

Comment: I don't quite get why there is downvote

Comment: I did not down vote you, but I have to say that the way you stated your question is not clear. Tthus, it may not be interpreted as the question in my first comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to avoid any <strike>heavy machinery</strike> topology, you can basically follow the proof of the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Note that every connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval.  Let $C$ denote the connected subspace in question.  If $f : C \to \mathbb{R}$ is two valued, then without loss of generality we may assume that $C = [ a , b ]$ where $a < b$ are such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$.  (The restriction of $f$ to such a subset will still be continuous.)

In the sequel we will always find $\delta > 0$ with respect to $\epsilon = f(a) - f(b) > 0$.  (Note that given $z \in [a,b]$ if $\delta > 0$ is such that $| f(x) - f(z) | < \epsilon$ for all $| x - z | < \delta$, then $f(x) = f(z)$ for all $| x - z | < \delta$.)

Consider $$s = \sup \{ x \in [a,b] : f(x) = f(a) \}.$$
Continuity of $f$ implies that $a < s < b$.  Let $\alpha = \min \{ s - a , b - a \}$.
Now what is $f(s)$?

- If $f(s) = f(a)$, then there is a $0 < \delta < \alpha$ such that $f(x) = f(s) = f(a)$ for all $| x - s | < \delta$.  In particular, $f ( s + \frac{\delta}{2} ) = f(s) = f(a)$, contradicting that $s$ is an upper bound of $\{ x \in [a,b] : f(x) = f(a) \}$.
- If $f(s) = f(b)$, then there is a $0 < \delta < \alpha$ such that $f(x) = f(s) = f(b)$ for all $| x - s | < \delta$.  This then implies that $s - \delta$ is an upper bound of $\{ x \in [a,b] : f(x) = f(a) \}$, contradicting that $s$ is the supremum of this set.

Comment: That's really a good answer but i want to why you need the $\alpha$, can't we just say there exist a $\delta$?